# Stripe to separate title and the rest

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-framework-7

I want to separate a title from the rest of the content with a line.

Any help is appreciated.

edit. Giving the div a border-bottom works perfectly

Comment: You can use <hr />

Comment: Welcome Max! We'll need some additional details in order to help solve your issue. Can you share your HTML structure, and the styles you've added already. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `<hr/>` in your html between the title and the text or something like this in your css:

```
h1 {
     border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Saveli Tomac suggested, your best bet is to use an `<hr/>` tag. Then, you have two options with this tag. You can use the tag by itself which will just be a solid line, or you can provide `style="border-top: dotted 1px;"` to give it a striped appearance.

```html
<h1>EXAMPLE ONE (HR)</h1>
<hr/>
<p>HERE IS THE BODY</p>

<h1>EXAMPLE 2 (DOTTED BORDER)</h1>
<hr style="border-top: dotted 1px;" />
<p> HERE IS THE BODY</p>
```